# How to add query string to page url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Currently I am using this code to give a user access by its `uuid` to a private page.

```
if (!!$.cookie('my_uuid_cookie')) {
      var my_uuid = $.cookie("my_uuid_cookie")
      var target = window.location.href + '?uuid=' + my_uuid;
      window.location.href = target;
}
```

First I check if the url does not contain any `uuid`. If not, I fire the code above.

This being said you may notice, that `window.location.href` forces a page reload, which does not look to good. Is there a way to "silently" add the query string to my url?

(The URL is not being necessary on page load, the user has to toggle another function by clicking on it. Thats the moment, when the query string is needed.)

Comment: Check out pushState: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method

Comment: window.history.pushState

Comment: Thanks this works great guys! Is there a more cross browser compatible solution as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

Note that will work only on HTML5 browsers

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method